# Flutter : About flutter_carousel_slider 1.1.0 Package // How to disappear or fade out current text to the new text When scolling carousel slider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Accoarding to the packgage[text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_slider)
I want to make a cube carousel slider image gallary same as the example of the package but the problem is I can't find a solution to make text on the image disaappear or fade out to the new one When scolling a cube image gallary. Please Help
[text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UdaraWanasinghe/FlutterCarouselSlider/master/screenrecord.gif)

I use a code follow along this package example but can't find the way to wrap text and make it disapper or fadeout when scolling a cube.